# shallowRef is not defined al importar componente en Vue 3 y Vite

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js, npm

Que tal colegas tengo el siguiente error:

> shallowRef is not defined

al importar cualquier componente o libreria ya sea directamente en un componente o globalmente lo importo de la siguiente manera:
Aqui lo importo individualmente en un componente y recibo el error:
**Cabe destacar que es con cualquier libreria o componente**

```
<script>
import Loading from "vue-loading-overlay";
import "vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css";
</script>
```

Cabe señalar que tengo las siguientes versiones:

```
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^1.2.1"
"vue": "^3.0.5",
```

Y en mi archivo vite.config.js tengo lo siguiente que es donde quiza viene el problema:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

Mi archivo main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/index'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import './index.css'

import Notifications from 'vt-notifications'
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router, VueAxios, axios, Notifications).mount('#app')
```

¿Saben cual es el error? de antemano gracias

Comment: La ultima version de plugin es 1.6 y vos tenes 1.2. Capaz por eso arroje errores con vue 3? Probaste actualizarlo?